# Using python how to make appium server wait on an particluar screen til a process is completed?

Tags: android, python, appium

I have initiated an copy process in android app, but the appium server backgrounds the app before the copy process is complete, i want the app to wait on copy screen till copy process is completed is there any way of doing it.

I tried using while loop

```
    result=self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_name("Ok"))

    while result==True:

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(999)
```

and also if loop

```
    if result==True:

         self.driver.implicitly_wait(999)

         print "Copy sucessfull"
```

Answer (score 1):

use time.sleep() for wait.For exp. if you want to wait for 5 seconds then write time.sleep(5)
To use it you have to use. "import time"

Comment: Thanks, do you know any way to make appium server wait on current line of code untill current process is completed and not jump to next line of code.?

Comment: I used time.sleep(), doesn't seem to work as intended

Comment: Even i am trying to do the same which u asking. But not getting any suitable idea for it.

Comment: i tried the command with while loop, it stopped at current process, but i could not find an way to exit from the loop, it formed an infinite loop.
     
    copy = self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_name("Copying Files"))
        while copy == True:
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        else:
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click() 
        
        copy = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Copying Files"))
        while copy:
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        else:
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click()